# Object doesn't support property or method 'multiselect'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-multiselect.js/css for a multi select dropdown. It worked fine on my localhost (both IE and Chrome). After deploying to a dev environment I am getting an error in IE (Chrome works fine):

> Object doesn't support property or method 'multiselect'

**Script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('[id*=lstMarket]').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    jQuery('[id*=lstGoalPeriod]').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
```

[image: object doesn't support property or method 'multiselect']

Where am I going wrong? Or is there any other way to call `multiselect()`?

Comment: Make sure that you have correctly referenced JQuery in the dev environment.

Comment: So it worked in IE on localhost but not on development? Are there any other errors in the console? Clear your cache and disable any browser plugins?

Comment: @j08691 Yes..For IE it worked on localhost but not on dev environment. There are only 2 errors from console. Above is the first one and the second one is from bootstrap-multiselect.js .. shows Expected identifier.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer and wanted to share if it helps to someone. This is caused by referencing a property named "class" (a reserved keyword) on an object in bootstrap-multiselect.js file. Refer the first error from the image below.

[image: Console errors]

To fix this, I have changed(line 1481 as shown in the image)

```
'class': option.class,
```

to

```
'class': 'option.class',
```

Now it's is working fine.